# Could not deploy code in ec2 using s3 bitbucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems.

Answer (score 0):

As per this link [1], this is an issue with Health Constraints. You will need to check the Deployment Configuration, if the agent(s) on the instances is connected to CodeDeploy service endpoint and how many instances actually succeeds the deployment.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/error-codes.html#ecode_health_constraints